# Disable brush resize (DC.js, D3.js)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Brush extent needs to be changed **only** from a dropdown as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/dani2011/67jopfj8/3/

**Need to disable brush extending by:**

**1) Extending an existing brush using the handles/resize-area of the brush**

Gray circles are the handels:

[image]

**2) Dragging a new brush by clicking on the brush background, where the 
    haircross cursor appears.**

**JavaScript file**

Removed the handles of the brush:

```
timeSlider.on('preRedraw',function (chart)
    {
        var timesliderSVG = d3.select("#bitrate-timeSlider-chart").selectAll("g.brush").selectAll("g.resize").selectAll("*").data(data[0]).exit().remove();})
```

If using css instead:

```
#bitrate-timeSlider-chart g.resize {
           display:none;
           visibility:hidden;
```

Now it looks like this:

[image].

The rect and the path elements inside "resize e","resize w" were removed:

[image]

However,the "resize e", "resize w" for extanding the brush still exist:

[image]

g.resize.e and g.resize.w dimesions are 0*0:

[image]

Furthurmore,after deleting "resize e","resize w" in the "developer tools/elements" in chrome,they reappear after moving the brush.

Tried to remove the resize-area in brushstart,brush,brushend:

```
timeSlider.on('renderlet', function (chart) {
var brushg = d3.select("#bitrate-timeSlider-chart").selectAll("g.brush");
var resizeg = brushg.selectAll("g.resize").selectAll("*").data(data[0]);       
var timesliderSVG4 = 
brushg.on("brushstart", function () {resizeg.exit().remove()}).on("brush", function () { resizeg.exit().remove() }).on("brushend", function () {resizeg.exit().remove() })
```

**dc.js file**

Tried to change **setHandlePaths**,**resizeHandlePath**:

**1)** 
Remarked the  _chart.**setHandlePaths**(gBrush):

```
_chart.renderBrush = function (g) {....
 //   _chart.setHandlePaths(gBrush);
 ...}
```

**2)** Changed  _chart.**setHandlePaths** = function (gBrush) for example by removing the **gbrush.path**:

```
  //  gBrush.selectAll('.resize path').exit().remove();
```

**3)** Remarked/changed  _chart.**resizeHandlePath** = function (d) {...}.

**d3.js file**

**1)** Remarked/changed **resize** such as:

`mode: "move" //mode: "resize"`  ,

```
var resize = g.selectAll(".resize").data(resizes[0], d3_identity);
```

Using resizes[0] disable the brush rendering on the background but still can re-extend the existing brush

**2)** Remarked/changed **d3_svg_brushResizes**

**3)** In d3.svg.brush = function():

**a)** Added .style("display","none"):

```
background.enter().append("rect").attr("class", "background").style("visibility", "hidden").style("display", "none").style("cursor", "none");
```

**b)** `background.exit().remove();`
The cursor now is "pointer" instead of "haircross" extending the brush to a full width

**c)**  **d3_svg_brushCursor** disabled makes the whole brush disappear

**4)** Changed the **pointer-events** as specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

**5)** console.log in different places to track the different brush events:

```
function d3_event_dragSuppress(node) {        
        console.log("here2 ");          
    }
    if (d3_event_dragSelect) {
        console.log("here3 d3_event_dragSelect");
        ...
    }
    return function (suppressClick) {
        console.log("suppressClick1");
        ...
            var off = function () {
                console.log("suppressClick2");
               ...
            w.on(click, function () {
                console.log("suppressClick3")
               ...    
    function d3_mousePoint(container, e) {
    console.log("d3_mousePoint1")
    ...
    if (svg.createSVGPoint) {
        console.log("createSVGPoint");
       ...
            if (window.scrollX || window.scrollY) {
                console.log("createSVGPoint1");
                svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").style({
                    ...

    function dragstart(id, position, subject, move, end) {
        console.log("dragstart")
       ...
            function moved() {
                console.log("moved ");

             console.log("transition1");
...
          if (d3.event.changedTouches) {
            console.log("brushstart1");
           ...
        } else {
            console.log("brushstart2");
           ..
        if (dragging) {
            console.log("dragging4");
           ....
            if (d3.event.keyCode == 32) {
                if (!dragging) {
                    console.log("notdragging1");
                    ...
        function brushmove() {
            console.log("brushmove");
            ...
            if (!dragging) {
                console.log("brushmove!dragging");
                if (d3.event.altKey) {
                    console.log("brushmove!dragging1");
                    ...
            if (resizingX && move1(point, x, 0)) {
                console.log("resizeXMove1");
              ...

            if (resizingY && move1(point, y, 1)) {
                console.log("resizeYMove1");
               ...
            if (moved) {
                console.log("moved");
                ...
        }
        function move1(point, scale, i) {
            if (dragging) {
                console.log("dragging1");
                ...
            if (dragging) {
                console.log("dragging2");
            ...
            } else {
                console.log("dragging10");
                ...
            if (extent[0] != min || extent[1] != max) {
                console.log("dragging11");
                if (i) console.log("dragging12"); yExtentDomain = null;    
                console.log("dragging13");            
        function brushend() {
            console.log("brushend");
        ...
```

**The two changes that seemed to get closest to the needed result are in d3.js:**

**1)** Using **resizes[0]** disables the brush rendering on the background but still can re-extend the existing brush

```
var resize = g.selectAll(".resize").data(resizes[0], d3_identity);
```

**2)** **Removing the brush's background** changes the cursor to "pointer" instead of "haircross",extending the brush to a full width only when clicking on the graph

```
`background.exit().remove();`
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen [*"Disable d3 brush resize"*](/q/23808436)? Make sure to not only read the accepted answer, there is valueable information in most of the other answers as well.

Comment: For taking control of the background click have a look at Mike Bostock's [*Click-to-Recenter Brush*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498000). Instead of the centering, you could just cancel the event.

Comment: Thank you for your references. Code from "Click-to-Recenter Brush" inside the .on(renderlet or .on('preRedraw' didn't change the result.  Also tried to cancel the event with d3.event.stopPropagation(). Furthermore,  the suggestions from "disable d3 brush resize" link did not  disable the resize option on the brush. Will update the code in my fiddle with the relevant code from these examples remarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the accepted answer in [Disable d3 brush resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808436/disable-d3-brush-resize), as suggested by @altocumulus. I didn't see a response from @Dani on this idea in particular, but thought I'd go ahead and try it, since I've seen other people try it in the past. (Probably on the [dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/dc-js-user-group).)

It looks a little twitchy, because d3.js will draw the brush at the new extent, and then a moment later we reset the extent to what we want, but functionally it seems to do what we want.

In dc.js the function that handles brush "rounding" is [`coordinateGridMixin.extendBrush`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/31682740c4b5cd8f26087db5515150cf64f948c9/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L1043):

```
_chart.extendBrush = function () {
    var extent = _brush.extent();
    if (_chart.round()) {
        extent[0] = extent.map(_chart.round())[0];
        extent[1] = extent.map(_chart.round())[1];

        _g.select('.brush')
            .call(_brush.extent(extent));
    }
    return extent;
};
```

Notice that it's following the same pattern as Lars' answer. Well, this is sort of like rounding, right? Let's override it.

First, let's store the current number of hours when it's set through the dropdown:

```
var graphSpan;
function addHours(amountHours) {
  graphSpan = amountHours;
  // ...
```

Next let's override `coordinateGridMixin.extendBrush`:

```
timeSlider.extendBrush = function() {
    var extent = timeSlider.brush().extent();
    if(graphSpan) {
        extent[1] = moment(extent[0]).add(graphSpan, 'hours');
    }
    return extent;
}
```

We just replace the function. If we needed to reuse the old implementation in our function, we could use [`dc.override`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/31682740c4b5cd8f26087db5515150cf64f948c9/src/core.js#L426).

If `graphSpan` has been set, we add that amount to the beginning to get the end. If it's not set, we allow the user to specify the brush width - you'd need to default the `graphSpan` and the select widget if you wanted that part to work automatically.

Well, let's admit it: it's **very** twitchy, but it works:

[image: twitchy fixed brush extent]

**EDIT:** Got rid of the twitch! The problem was that dc.js was setting the brush extent asynchronously after a little while (in response to the filter event). If we also set it during `extentBrush` then it never shows the wrong extent:

```
timeSlider.extendBrush = function() {
    var extent = timeSlider.brush().extent();
    if(graphSpan) {
      extent[1] = moment(extent[0]).add(graphSpan, 'hours');
      timeSlider.brush().extent(extent);
    }
    return extent;
}
```

[image: nicer brush resize]

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/xdo05chk/1/

Comment: Thank you very very much Gordon- for your time,clear explanations and work-I really appreciate your help in resolving this problem! Dani

Comment: Sure thing, Dani! These days I feel it's worth the effort to figure out and write up canonical answers for common questions like this one. And SO amplifies the power of those answers - I see less and less questions repeated.

Comment: One more question regarding the solution:When I drag the line charts, the size of the brush on the timeChart still changes. Tried to change this by applying the  timeSlider.extendBrush inside the bitChart2.on('postRedraw', with and without dc.renderall(). Also tried to implement the same code in other events such as bitChart2.on('renderlet'. Futhurmore try to override  _chart.redrawBrush  inside.on('postRedraw' of bitchart2. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you do `mouseZoomable(false)` on the focus charts? I meant to try this in my answer but I forgot. They don't have brushes so the same code won't help. However a feature of focus / range charts is to update the brush on the range chart when the zoom or pan of the focus charts change, so that's probably the problem. I suppose pan but not zoom would make sense in this scenario.

Comment: mouseZoomable(false) disables the panning of the line charts by the user,the update of data in the table and the resize of the brush.Tried to affect the brush of the range chart from within the event of the focus chart. Looking now into pan but not zoom and disabling the brush change of the range chart by the focus chart.Thank you (:

Comment: I can't follow this in comments. Please open another question and state clearly what is the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: Please find an update to the code which enables to continue the brush-extent from its current position on the range chart:                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254816/how-to-continue-the-brush-extent-from-its-current-position-on-the-range-chart-d

Comment: Oh, this wasn't a question, it was an update. Sorry I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

in d3:

disable resize handles
    `d3.selectAll('.brush>.handle').remove();`

disable crosshair
    `d3.selectAll('.brush>.overlay').remove();`

**or**
in css:

disable resize handles -

```
.handle {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

disable crosshair -

```
.overlay {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```